# UILocalNotification Fires only once in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ibeacon

I am developing an iBeacon Application which is using local notifications to alert user when he enters/exits from specific region. But I am getting notification only once when the application in background. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = nil;
    notification.alertBody = @"Welcome";
    notification.alertAction = @"View";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = nil;
    notification.alertBody = @"Thank you for coming";
    notification.alertAction = @"View";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "only once", like only when you enter the region or leaving the region?

Comment: When I am entering into the region I am getting notification after that no more notifications. If the application is in foreground, getting notifications

Answer (score 2):

The methods didEnterRegion and didExitRegion has some time interval values. These methods fires after some time. And be sure to exit region completely. In addition you can use the method didDetermineState.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Testing an iOS App’s Region Monitoring Support

> When testing your region monitoring code in iOS Simulator or on a
>   device, realize that region events may not happen immediately after a
>   region boundary is crossed. To prevent spurious notifications, iOS
>   doesn’t deliver region notifications until certain threshold
>   conditions are met. Specifically, the user’s location must cross the
>   region boundary, move away from the boundary by a minimum distance,
>   and remain at that minimum distance for at least 20 seconds before the
>   notifications are reported.
>
> The specific threshold distances are determined by the hardware and
>   the location technologies that are currently available. For example,
>   if Wi-Fi is disabled, region monitoring is significantly less
>   accurate. However, for testing purposes, you can assume that the
>   minimum distance is approximately 200 meters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If application is in foreground alerts getting triggered for the events properly

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you wait up to 15 minutes to get a call to `didEnterRegion` / `didExitRegion` before you conclude it does not work.  On some devices, detection can take that long.  See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html).

I would add `NSLog` lines to your callbacks so you can see whether they are getting called at all -- I suspect they are not.  If true, this means the problem is with detections, not the notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If application is in foreground alerts getting triggered for the events properly

Comment: Do you also have ranging enabled?  If so, it will eliminate any delays when your app is in the foreground, but the delays will exist when your app is in the background.